# Add custom information to text fields to use with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m making a google instant-type of remote suggestion script with ajax on a site I'm making.

now I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="spanishtitle" onkeyup="suggest(this, 'title_es');" onblur="fill();" />
```

and I would like to move that onkeyup script to a jquery call, so I added this

```
$('.suggestable').live('keyup', ( function() { suggest(this); } ));
```

and changed the above to this

```
 <input class="suggestable" type="text" name="spanishtitle" onblur="fill();" />
```

but I'm missing the 'title_es' parameter which tells the ajax handler what am I looking for.

So what I want to know, basically, is if there's a way to add this parameter to the object, so I can access it from suggest() somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to your HTML...

```
<input type="text" name="spanishtitle" onblur="fill();" data-title="title_es" />
```

And then access it in jQuery...

```
$('.suggestable').live('keyup',
      function() { suggest(this, $(this).attr('data-title')); }
);
```

The `data-` prefixed attributes are in the HTML5 spec, and are going to be very useful.

At last, no further excuses for using inline event attributes :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign it as the id of the element and then

```
$('.suggestable').live('keyup', function() { 
    suggest(this, $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

The `data-*` attribute is html5 as far as I know

Answer (score -1):

You can add it as an attribute to the input, something like:

```
<input data-lookfor='title_es' class="suggestable" type="text" name="spanishtitle" onblur="fill();" />
```

then you can access it in jQuery with .attr()

```
var look_for = $(this).attr('data-lookfor');
```

Comment: adding arbitrarily named attributes is a bad idea. Extra attributes should have names beginning with "data-" i.e. "data-lang" or "data-field" etc.

Comment: That's a good point. I forgot that data- was in the html5 spec. I edited my answer so it doesn't confuse the situation.